# jquery and javascript not work on prettyphoto loaded html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, prettyphoto

prettyphoto shows my form in a modal box. I inserted a link in form and set `onclick="$('#formid').submit()"`. when i clicked it, page navigate to form action but without any posted data. when i replace link with a input `<input type="submit" value="ok">` it send form data correctly.
I test jquery element access with calling a function. result, showed that jquery cant access elements value.
I put some html in form by jquery but noting happend also after reloading modal box it shown.
is there any solution to access prettyphoto loaded html form by  jquery and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

`submit()` in jquery works on `<form>` element, so that best way to do it to put a submit button in the form but do it such a way that it is hidden from view like:

```
<input id='dummy' type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
```

And in your jquery when the anchor link is clicked you simulate a submitting of the submit button by clicking it like this one below:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#dummy').trigger('click');
  });
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/Rz9Hy/2/) for you to check. Be aware though that I used a real website to simulate it but it will not receive the posted data.

Comment: When i use prettyphoto jquery operations don't act on modal box.

Comment: @sajadnabavi can you post some code in your original post (OP)? So that I could check.

Comment: The issue isn't jQuery, as jQuery can do the work - The problem is that the element you're looking for is re-created within the PrettyPhoto pop-up. If your element doesn't contain an ID (unique element), then you can use the 'live()' monitor pre-1.9 or .on() for 1.10+ - If an element ID is to be used then you need to modify prettyPhoto so that it removes the element when it adds it to the modal window, then puts it back once you close it.